# How to get all Ids of a Checkbox which are inside the fieldset element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get all Ids of `CheckBoxes` which are inside of a `Fieldset` element by using `jQuery`?

Below is what I tried so far..

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on("click", "a[id$='btnShowRates']", function (e) {
  //for selecting checkboxes when page loads first time
  var everyChildcb = document.querySelectorAll('[id$=listRateCats] input[type=checkbox]');

  //I also tried like below but not working

  //var everyChildcb = document.querySelectorAll("#listRates");
});
```

**HTML code:**
HTML Code contains an `fieldset` element inside it there are multiple `CheckBoxes` can be seen in below HTML snippet..

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="listRates" data-icon="false" runat="server">
  <div style='position:relative;'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='1' data-display-name='Rack/General' />
    <label for='1'>Rack/General</label>
    <img id='img_1' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
  </div>
  <div style='position:relative;'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='4' data-display-name='Government' />
    <label for='4'>Government</label>
    <img id='img_4' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
  </div>
  <div style='position:relative;'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='6' data-display-name='Package' />
    <label for='6'>Package</label>
    <img id='img_6' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
  </div>
  <div style='position:relative;'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='3' data-display-name='Family' />
    <label for='3'>Family</label>
    <img id='img_3' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Appreciate any help and suggestions, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the map() function to get the id's as an array.

```
var ids = $("fieldset :checkbox").map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
console.log(ids)
```

Or you can just loop through the checkboxes to get the id's. For looping you can use `.each()`. In the loop context you can use `this.id` to get the id of the current looped checkbox

```
$("fieldset :checkbox").each(function() {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4110/)

Comment: Anoop, `.map` result would look pretty with `.get()` :)

Comment: Check `console.log(ids)` and check `console.log(ids.get())`..So `$("fieldset :checkbox").map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get()` will go good :)

Comment: @Rayon yes you are correct. It looks better now. I will edit my answer. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: Thanks, I have one more query that now as I get the ids am wants to call the function -   
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->
function setCustomChecked(checked, context){}

like -
for (var i in ids) {
            setCustomChecked(false, ids[i]);
        }
but as context requires- input#abr property value = "on" attribute value = "null"

But now what is in context is =abr/rack...

Comment: what is your actual requirement? There should be another easy ways to do the stuff.

Comment: I want to pass [input#abr property value = "on" attribute value = "null"] in context now simply abr/rack is passes..
please check fiddle - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/RSH1991/a6dx2upo/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#listRates').find('input:checkbox').each(function(){
alert($(this).attr('id'))//get each checkbox id

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="listRates" data-icon="false" runat="server">

  <div style='position:relative;'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='1' data-display-name='Rack/General' />
    <label for='1'>Rack/General</label>
    <img id='img_1' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
  </div>
  <div style='position:relative;'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='4' data-display-name='Government' />
    <label for='4'>Government</label>
    <img id='img_4' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
  </div>
  <div style='position:relative;'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='6' data-display-name='Package' />
    <label for='6'>Package</label>
    <img id='img_6' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
  </div>
  <div style='position:relative;'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='3' data-display-name='Family' />
    <label for='3'>Family</label>
    <img id='img_3' class='checkboxFixIconLeft' />
  </div>

</fieldset>
► Run code snippet
```

Use `.each()`